# Solr... how to make search and correction word together?

Tags: java, solr, match, phrases

I have two list (really there are many ) that  i need to match between them. for example:

I have a documents like:

- Manchester United
- Arsenal FC
- Wigan
- ...

Second list is like:

- Manchester U.
- Arsenal
- Wigan FC
- ...

so, i need to query if each words of second list exists into the first list (and correct it if apply).

i can't use dictionary because the word list changes always.
each list word can have multi-word.

i was looking some approach like N-gram, spellchecker, etc... but i am confused because these approach works letter by letter (for example first "M", second "Ma"...) 
and i don't know what to do or start.
how do you resolve this problem? 
regards!